# python-scipy test freeze in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, python

I have a new installation of Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS. Running the test of python-scipy failed to go through and stopped as the display below.

```
scipy.test()
Running unit tests for scipy
NumPy version 1.6.1
NumPy is installed in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy
SciPy version 0.9.0
SciPy is installed in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy
Python version 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) [GCC 4.6.3]
nose version 1.1.2
```

This happens to my another installation of Xubuntu 12.04 as well. How can I get the problem resolved?

Thanks in advance.

---

Update: It is related to autofs. Removing autofs resolved the issue.

Comment: Could you post your solution with some more detail in an answer and accept it? This will help future users experiencing a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is in response to maggotbrain's request of posing the solution as an answer.

Solution:
remove autofs using the aptitude tool

For previously mounted FS using autofs, you can use soft link or 'mount --bind' for local folders, or configure /etc/fstab for network drives.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested scipy.test() on my vps running Ubuntu 12.04 Server. I install numpy, scipy, nose via apt.I run the test from a Python console. The test failed but that's another issue. [See my scipy.test() output.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5646480/) How do you run the test? I guess it was running, somehow you just didn't see the output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My further tests just revealed that the issue was related to autofs mount as well, even though I have no idea why autofs is causing this. I removed autofs and this problem got resolved automatically. scipy.test() can run now, with exactly the same error message as your output. And I got the same output from several of my Ubuntu installations.